# linq insert: getting the row number

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with the primary key as the identity column. I'm doing an insert with linq-to-sql and I was wondering if there's a way to return the ID of the row that was inserted and how we know for sure that the insert happened.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key property of the entity that was used for the insert will be updated after the call to SubmitChanges with the ID from the database.

Ex:

```
using (var dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();

    dc.MyEntities.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

    int pkValue = entity.PKColumn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ-to-SQL it will update any IDENTITY (etc) properties during the save automatically, so just look at `.Id` (or whatever).

Re knowing it happened: updates etc happen in a transaction; that transaction must have committed to have got out of the method without an exception. If you have an outer `TransactionScope` (or similar) then that it up to you to commit; in short - until you do commit you have a phantom record. As such, avoid passing that new id anywhere until you have committed all your transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The identity of the inserted record should automatically populate the object which was added to the `DataContext` for the insert.  Just check the ID on that object.

Additionally, you can look at the `GetChangeSet()` method on the `DataContext` to [see what changes it has tracked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) if you want more manual information about the number of affected records, etc..